# TYPO3 Backend Error VHS ResourceViewHelper

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, viewhelper

I updated a TYPO3 Installation from 6.2. to 7.6 and now I have the problem, that I always get an error after clicking on the Page Settings. I always get:

> Could not analyse class: "Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers_Extension_Path_ResourcesViewHelper" maybe not
>   loaded or no autoloader? Class
>   Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers_Extension_Path_ResourcesViewHelper does not
>   exist"

Some relevant Extension in the installation:

- crawler
- fluid
- fluid_styled_content
- fluidcontent
- formhandler
- ke_search
- news
- realurl

Maybe someone of you have an idea why this appears only at the page settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because at least one template is rendered (or at least parsed) where you use the VHS ViewHelper `ResourcesViewHelper` with its old class name from the pre namespace era.

Scan your fluid templates (most likely page templates) for the old VHS namespace declaration

```
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}
```

and change it to

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
```

You can also switch to declaring the namespace in the HTML tag like this:

```
<html
    xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
    xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers" 
    data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem.
There are 3 Hompages in this Installation and the Mainpage was running without any problems, but on another site i forgot this changes!